# Get list of users which have a specific or set of permissions

Tags: shiro, jdbcrealm

Using Shiro with JDBCRealm

My use case requires a user to submit a form to next user. The next user can only be someone with specific permission. This is to be known in order to show only valid Next user list for selection.

How can I get list of all the users that have a specific permission?
If not, Is there a workaround of getting the User permission strings from database and then at least reuse Shiro's logic to check if the user has specific permission?

Answer (score 0):

Shiro is related to only security, authority, etc of current user not to the whole user base. You can use your standard sql queries to retrieve users with same permissions of the current logged in subject.

Why not use simple SQL query that  matches current user permissions to other users permission and give a list. This way you will save memory and resource by not computing permissions logic in java again.

Comment: Thought of doing that. Example : If I am looking for users with a.b.c permission then I also need to select users with a.* and a.*.c. Cant think of query which does that. Other way I can think of is getting list of all permissions then iterating through them and reimplementing shiro logic to know if a permission string(a.b.c) is permitted under given permission (a.*) or (a.*.c). Wanted to know if there is more efficient way?

Comment: what about a query with (permission like a:%) or  (permission like a:%:c) like these.